# What gets carried over on a new game plus in Fire Emblem: Three Houses?

Tags: fire-emblem-three-houses

On new game +, does it let you..

- Keep class masteries
- change mode (classic/classic)
- keep your inventory storage
- keep permanent stat gains from Items

Or, is Renown the only thing that you can keep and everything’s back to scratch?

I’ve read articles that mention that on new game plus, you get to keep renown but it wasn’t exactly specific on the above

Answer (score 6):

From my own experience with new game+, I can confirm that:

- My Saint Statue Levels remain as they were.
- All my Battalions (Purchased ones, Quest Reward ones, and Paralogue reward ones) are
  all as they were, including level.
- Extra renown that I had, I started the game with about 5000 Renown.

Everything else is returned to the beginning:

- you don't keep any items, including lost items, fishing bait, weapons, nothing.
- you don't keep your unlocked merchants, I no longer have Anna's secret shop, the East/South merchants, nor the blacksmith.
- you don't keep any skill mastery for Byleth, nor any other units.
- you don't keep any support ranks.
- you don't keep any levels or experience or class mastery for Byleth or any other units.
- you can't buy any different items in the shops

The new thing you do have is called the Journal, its in your bedroom. Using the journal, you can do the following:

- you can alter the appearance of those in your party (even those you recruit) to either their Pre- or Post- time skip look. This changes the model only, so they will walk around and do battle as whichever you choose, however their voice and portrait will remain the default depending on where you are in the story.
- you can spend renown on multiple new things, a note on this is everything can only be upgraded to the level you had it in your first play through. For example I got Byleth's sword skill to A on my first play through, so I could only spend Renown to get it back to A, not A+, S, or S+.

  1. you can upgrade your professor level, which is a huge help early on.
  2. you can upgrade the weapon skill of any character in your party.
  3. you can buy the class mastery reward for any character in your party, of any class that character mastered in your first play through.
  4. you can purchase crest stones for 1000 Renown each, these are items that when just held in the inventory (not equipped, so you can still have a shield) give a special bonus effect. For me, most were available for purchase but not all, It may be that the owner of the crest needs to be on your party in some play through, as I went through first as Black Eagles, then on NG+ I went Golden Deer, I'll have to confirm if its the Blue Lions crests that I'm missing.
  5. you can upgrade your support with units, again only as far as you got in your first play through.

Answer (score 5):

According to [GamesRadar+](https://www.gamesradar.com/fire-emblem-three-houses-new-game-plus/) and [Gamers Heroes](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/fire-emblem-three-houses-new-game-guide/)

- You can keep:

  - Renown
  - hired Battalions
  - unlocked merchants
  - Saint Statue levels and rewards
- You can buy new items in the shops
- You can change your army's appearance
- You gain more Renown than before
- You can spend Renown to:

  - upgrade your Professor Level
  - upgrade the Skill Level of any of your characters
  - upgrade Support
  - unlock Combat Arts
  - unlock Abilities
  - unlock Classes
  - purchase Crest Signs, which grant Crest Powers to whoever holds the Sign